# When to use override in these two different ways

Tags: solidity, override

In these two examples from the AccessControl library, override is used differently, one is more specific. When does it necessitate using it in one format over another?

```
    function grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) public override(AccessControl, IAccessControl) {
        super.grantRole(role, account);
        _roleMembers[role].add(account);
    }
```

And

```
  function getRoleMemberCount(bytes32 role) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _roleMembers[role].length();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the documentation explains this better than I would do. Check it out:[image]

Long history short, you need to specifiy the contracts if you are overriding from more than one contract. Otherwise, you just need to use the override keyword.